# Lucene 3.0.3 - How is fuzzy search similarity correlated to later versions edit distance? (e.g. 4.x)

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Prior to versions 4.x, you set the similarity for a fuzzy search with a float between 0.1 to 1.0.
Later versions use a value between 0 and 2 as edit distances.

How are these values correlated? I cannot find anywhere in the documentation what an actual float range from 0.1 to 1.0 means.

I'm using lucene.net 3.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 4.0 onward just use a [Damerau-Levenshtein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance).

Version 3.0.3 instead compares the edit distance to the length of the term.  If `length(term) * minSimilarity >= edit distance` (where minSimilarity is the float argument you are referring to), the term is considered a match.

So, if you set it to 0.5, a term of length 4 could have an edit distance of up to 2, while a term of length 6 could have a distance of 3 and still be a match.